# Should I put a comma before and or not in this sentence?

Tags: commas

This law, is also very bad tourism as well, and needs to be removed since our country is being opened up for tourism.

Should I remove the comma before and or keep it? is there anything else wrong with the punctuation in this sentence?

Comment: I think you meant to say: "This law is also very bad for tourism as well, and needs to be removed ..."

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to remove the comma before and. You usually use a comma before any coordinating conjunction (and, but, for, yet, nor, so, or) that links two independent clauses.

Comment: @Cascabel Xena is right since there are not two independent clauses.

Comment: @BillJ Sorry, you are right and I mis-read it.. I just back from the opthamologists and my vision is a little tricky right now. What about the first comma?

Comment: There are two independent clauses here; the second clause is simply elided. (1) This law is also very bad tourism as well. (2) [This law] needs to be removed since our country is being opened up for tourism. However, having said that, a comma isn't *always* required in front of a conjunction between two independent clauses (although I don't think it's ever wrong). It's a matter of style. (As you say, it's *usually* used.)

Answer (score 0):

If the para is taken from any legal discussion or statute book.
It can be relied upon it's correctness as the legislature intentionally uses such kind of language for the better interpretation of it.